# How to add/update user certificate in WSO2 using the API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have several users in WSO2 IS 5.9 and I need to enable x509 certificate authentication. The certificate will be validated by a third party, and once I have the ok from this party, I will create the user in WSO2 IS and add its certificate to wso2 is to enable certificate authentication.

Is it possible to add the certificate of a user using the wso2 API, to avoid the process of adding it to the keystore using the OS shell?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The API is available from 5.10.0 release. Please refer to the [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/keystore-rest-api/).

Comment: Hi, update the IS is not something we have in the road map and we cannot afford it. Is there another way?